# How to compare two datetimeoffset using UTC datetime with mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to compare 2 datetimeoffset with 2 different time zones with mongodb c# driver. 
I'm using the document serialization for datetimeoffset that create an object that include:
- datetime in UTC
- ticks in LOCAL
- offset

I want to compare only the datetime part of the object because "2019-05-03 10:00:00 +01" are equal to "2019-05-03 09:00:00 +00".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods that can compare `DateTimeOffset`.  The methods compare the UTC value of the `DateTimeOffset`

[Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.compare?view=netframework-4.8) returns an int:

```
var c = DateTimeOffset.Compare(dto1, dto2);
// c > 0: dto1 is later
// c < 0: dto2 is later
// c == 0: dto1 and dto2 are the same in UTC
```

[CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) similar to compare (different syntax), returns an int:

```
var c = dto1.CompareTo(dto2);
// c > 0: dto1 is later
// c < 0: dto2 is later
// c == 0: dto1 and dto2 are the same in UTC
```

[Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.equals?view=netframework-4.8) returns boolean:

```
var c = dto1.Equals(dto2);
// True: dto1 and dto2 have the same value in UTC
// False: dto1 and dto2 do not have the same UTC value
```

[EqualsExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.equalsexact?view=netframework-4.8) compares the offset as well as the time, and returns a bool:

```
var c = dto1.EqualsExact(dto2);
// True: dto1 and dto2 have the same value in UTC AND the same Offset
// False: dto1 and dto2 do not have the same UTC value or do not have the same Offset
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IIXhnh).

Comment: My problem is with MongoDB c# driver. I've tried to use your solution but the driver is unable to translate Equals, EqualsExact or CompareTo. Thanks